# Jcrop lose focus when pressing esc key or random mouse click

Tags: javascript, jquery, jcrop

I am using Jcrop for cropping my image. My problem is that when i press Esc key or click randomly anywhere on image then jcrop loses focus. I want to prevent users from doing same. My code is as below

```
           $('#cropbox').Jcrop({
                        aspectRatio: 1,
                        addClass:'jcrop-holder1',
                        setSelect: [ 100, 100, 825, 446 ],
                        minSize: [100,100],
                        onSelect: updateCoords,
                        onChange: updateCoords,
           });
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function parseKey(e) //{{{
{
    if (e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey) {
        return true;
    }
    shift_down = e.shiftKey ? true : false;
    var nudge = shift_down ? 10 : 1;

    switch (e.keyCode) {
        case 37:
            doNudge(e, -nudge, 0);
            break;
        case 39:
            doNudge(e, nudge, 0);
            break;
        case 38:
            doNudge(e, 0, -nudge);
            break;
        case 40:
            doNudge(e, 0, nudge);
            break;
            /*
        case 27:
            if (options.allowSelect) Selection.release();
            break;*/
        case 9:
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

just command case 27 in this parseKey function(jquery.jcrop.js).